# Rails 3 create default nested objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a form where the user signs up and creates an Account, an User and a Website.

```
def new
  @account = Account.new
  @account.users.build
  @account.websites.build
  ...
end

def create
  @account = Account.new(params[:account])
  ...
```

Everything works fine. Now, I want to create a default Page with Page.title = "homepage" and Page.body = "".

How can I do that? I tried different options and it doesn't work. For example, I do this `@account.websites.pages.build` and I get this `undefined method pages for []:ActiveRecord::Relation`.

Comment: try `@account.websites.build.pages.build`

Comment: Tried but I get undefined method title for nil class `@account.websites[0].pages[0].title = "homepage"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collection returned by `@account.websites` is an array, rails can't intuit which member of the collection you're trying to create an associated object on... You need to specify which website you want to build a page for, ie

```
@account.websites.first.pages.build
```